# Javascript - .addEventListener('click') shows undefined when console.log(item[i])

Tags: javascript

I have some buttons like so:

```
<button data-value="50">50</button>
<button data-value="100">100</button>
<button data-value="150">150</button>
```

And I create an event listener like so:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]');
setupButtonListener(buttons);

function setupButtonListener(buttons) {
    for(var i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(buttons[i]);
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
}
```

Now the `console.log(buttons[i]);` outputs undefined

And the `console.log(this);` outputs `<button> data-value="100">100</button>`

is this normal? If not why would button[i] not work as I expected?

Comment: take a look at javascript [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: The for loop will not persist what you put into each button event listener. Use a forEach instead. And also, why is there a l = ... You can just say `i < buttons.length`